# Finding evidence of mongo remote access or collection wiping post-mortem

Tags: mongodb

I had some very unimportant, largely abandoned mongo-based sites running on  machine that's typically fairly well locked down, but after migrating them to this machine, the default mongo port was left open.

Unfortunately, I had never enabled query logging, so I'm trying to find any other possible avenues of finding out if this was the case.

I've looked through `~/.dbshell` though I double that will capture commands/queries run by remote clients, since it's tied to the system user. There's no evidence there.

I don't see any indication that mongo keeps an access log, so is there any other possible way for me to tell:

- Whether anyone connected from outside localhost
- Which commands they may have run

I doubt there's any hope at this point.

Comment: Are you looking for evidence of someone accessing an unsecured instance remotely, or have your collections actually been wiped? You could start by grepping for "connection accepted" messages in your `mongod` logs to see if there are unknown IP addresses and also check if your IP(s) are listed as open in a site like [Shodan](https://www.shodan.io). The current round of attackers have apparently been using existing sources (eg Shodan API) to find open hosts.There won't be any evidence in local files like `~/.dbshell` unless someone has remote shell access.

Comment: Yes and yes. I discovered all collections had been wiped, and the only theory I have is that someone found the open port used it. The port wasn't supposed to be open. I'm looking for any indication someone connected - if I have that, I can pretty much two and two together. Anyway, looking at that log, it's clear it's been accessed.